# Update scala DF based on events

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm running into Scala,Apache Spark world and I'm trying to understand how to create a "pipeline" that will generate a DataFrame based on the events I receive.

For instance, the idea is that when I receive a specific log/event I have to insert/update a row in the DF.

Let's make a real example.
I would like to create a DataFrame that will represent the state of the users present in my database(postgres,mongo whatever). 
When i say state, I mean the current state of the user(ACTIVE,INCOMPLETE,BLOCKED, etc). This states change based on the users activity, so then I will receive logs(JSON) with key "status": "ACTIVE" and so on.

So for example, I'm receiving logs from a Kafka topic.. at some point I receive a log which I'm interested because it defines useful information about the user(the status etc..) 
I take this log, and I create a DF with this log in it.
Then I receive the 2nd log, but this one was performed by the same user, so the row needs to be updated(if the status changed of course!) so no new row but update the existing one. Third log, new user, new information so store as a new row in the existing DF.. and so on.
At the end of this process/pipeline, I should have a DF with the information of all the users present in my db and their `"status"` so then I can say "oh look at that, there are 43 users that are `blocked` and 13 that are `active`! Amazing!"

This is the idea.. the process must be in real time.

So far, I've tried this using files not connecting with a kafka topic.
For instance, I've red file as follow:

```
val DF = mysession.read.json("/FileStore/tables/bm2ube021498209258980/exampleLog_dp_api-fac53.json","/FileStore/tables/zed9y2s11498229410434/exampleLog_dp_api-fac53.json")
```

which generats a DF with 2 rows with everything inside.

```
+--------------------+-----------------+------+--------------------+-----+
|                 _id|           _index|_score|             _source|_type|
+--------------------+-----------------+------+--------------------+-----+
|AVzO9dqvoaL5S78GvkQU|dp_api-2017.06.22|     1|[2017-06-22T08:40...|DPAPI|
|    AVzO9dq5S78GvkQU|dp_api-2017.06.22|     1|[null,null,[Wrapp...|DPAPI|
+--------------------+-----------------+------+--------------------+-----+
```

in `_source` there are all the nested things(the `status` I mentioned is here!).

Then I've selected some useful information like

```
DF.select("_id", "_source.request.user_ip","_source.request.aw", "_type").show(false)

+--------------------+------------+------------------------------------+-----+
|_id                 |user_ip     |aw                                  |_type|
+--------------------+------------+------------------------------------+-----+
|AVzO9dqvoaL5S78GvkQU|111.11.11.12|285d5034-dfd6-44ad-9fb7-ba06a516cdbf|DPAPI|
|AVzO9dq5S78GvkQU    |111.11.11.82|null                                |DPAPI|
+--------------------+------------+------------------------------------+-----+
```

again, the idea is to create this DF with the logs arriving from a kafka topic and upsert the log in this DF.
Hope I explained well, I don't want a "code" solution I'd prefer hints or example on how to achieve this result. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for resources I would suggest the following:
Have a look at the Spark Streaming Programming Guide (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) and the Spark Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html).

Use the Spark Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide for information on how to open a Stream with your Kafka content.
Then have a look at the possible transformations you can perform with Spark Streaming on it in chapter "Transformations on DStreams" in the Spark Streaming Programming Guide
Once you have transformed the stream in a way that you can perform a final operation on it have a look at "Output Operations on DStreams" in the Spark Streaming Programming Guide. I think especially `.forEachRDD` could be what you are looking for - as you can do an operation (like checking whether a certain key word is in your string and based on this do a database call) for each element of the stream.